# Ruby find and replace for each string occurrence in file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm wondering the best way to accomplish this with Ruby. What I'm wanting is to wrap everything after each found occurrence in the file with `query: [ ... ]`, and to save the file.

The example text file would be:

```
def ronny
  ronny :create, id: 1, location: nil
end

def alex
  alex :delete, id: 1, location: nil
end

def brandy
  brandy :update, id: 1, location: 555.32
end

def tyson
  tyson :read, id: 1, location: nil
end

def sonap
  sonap :delete, id: 1, location: 31.23
end
```

An example result would be:

```
ronny :create, query: [ id: 1, location: nil ]
```

or

```
brandy :update, query: [ id: 1, location: 555.32 ]
```

The expected saved text file result should read something like:

```
def ronny 
  ronny :create, query: [ id: 1, location: nil ]
end

def alex 
  alex :delete, query: [ id: 1, location: nil ]
end

def brandy 
  brandy :update, query: [ id: 1, location: 555.32 ]
end

def tyson 
  tyson :read, query: [ id: 1, location: nil ]
end

def sonap 
  sonap :delete, query: [ id: 1, location: 31.23 ]
end
```

Any ideas??

Comment: If you have 5 of those, just do it by hand. Otherwise, you'll need to learn something about regexes.

Comment: It of course could be done by hand.. But I'm curious to know how to do it in Ruby!

Answer (score 0):

```
.gsub(/(id: \d+, location: [\d|\.|nil]+)/){|m| "query: [#{m}]"}
#=> "ronny :create, query: [id: 1, location: nil]"
```

Comment: This is great. Except unfortunately I have a larger file where `location` isn't necessarily the last parameter. What would this `gsub` look like if it just looked for the end of the line to put the last bracket, instead of `location`?

Answer (score 0):

To wrap everything after `name :action,` into `query: []`, despite the parameters names:

```
input.gsub(/(?<=,)((\s*\w+:\s*\w+,?)+)/) do |m|
  " query: [#{m.strip}]"
end
```